Can't Find Installed React Native Android App On Phone and Emulator?
So something strange happened, when developing I noticed that my react-native app compiled but wasn't visible (not found on the apps list/tray) on my emulator although the react-native run-android launches it (both debug and release) but when I go to Settings > Apps I can see the app listed there, I thought this was some new thing to react for dev environments, but I noticed that after compiling my app as release I can't find it on the phone until I go to Settings > Apps and even from there I can't launch.
Another thing I first noticed was, that the first time I compile the release, while trying to install a notice appeared on my screen saying, Google play connect rejected my app, and at first I couldn't install the app, but after rerunning the compilation I was able to, but now the app can't be launched.
I tried to re-build , did ./gradelw clean and also update the build version nothing works for me .

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

SOLUTION
I had this problem and the issue is that i put  inside the same intent-filter as action and category.
Just take data out and put it in another intent-filter like:
 
Thats solve the problem for me :)
